# How to access get method in a Test Class Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, get, phpunit

I have to write a test class to test my service methods. In my controllers I could access the service by doing `$service = $this->get('myService');` and I could access my methods by doing `$service->someMethod();`. 
Now I want to write a test class to test some of the service methods, I tried doing like the doc :

```
class ServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testSomeMethod() {
        $service = $this->get('myService');
        ....
    }
}
```

When I launch the test I get something like :
 `Fatal error : Call to undefined method XXX\XXXBundle\Tests\Services\ServicesTest::get() in ...` 
So my question is how can I use get method to be able to call my service methods

Comment: Take a look at my answer, its the right approach of unit testing a service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your services you should extend the `KernelTestCase` class.

```
class ServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $service;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->service = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('my_service')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexandruOlaru, I tested it at first but it seems like I did something wrong now it's working just fine. much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

**You don't need to use the container** in order to test services and other classes. 
You should create a new instance of the class and inject the dependencies using test doubles.

**Test doubles**
- since you don't want to write a functional testing and to use the real dependencies you should be using a test double. 
for example if one of the service dependencies is the `EntityManager` what would happen is that a new entries would be inserted into the Database (or deleted from it) and its not the purpose of Unit testing (you do need to check this tho if you are writing a functional test).

And that's how you should approach this kind of testings:

```
public function testSomeServiceAdd()
{
    $dependencyOne = $this->getMockBuilder('Acme\SomeBundle\DependencyOne')->
        disableOriginalConstructor()->
        getMock();

    $dependencyTwo = $this->getMockBuilder('Acme\SomeBundle\DependencyTwo')->
        disableOriginalConstructor()->
        getMock();

    $service = new SomeService($dependencyOne, $dependencyTwo);

    $response = $service->add(1, 2);

    $this->assertEquals($response, 3);
}
```

As you can see I am "mocking" the dependencies and injecting it into the service, after that i'm calling the method and asserting the result.

I would also like to suggest a Mocking framework instead of using the built-in PHPUnit mocking functions. it's easier to use and it has much more mocking functionality:
https://github.com/danrevah/ShortifyPunit

Comment: I misunderstood the question so I deleted it. Tour answer is the good one after I've read again OP question